# How to write android apps with Enthought Canopy

Tags: android, enthought, canopy

Does anyone know if this is possible? I have searched without any success. Is it possible to get Kivy to work in Canopy?

Cheers
Graham

Answer (score 1):

There is no special support for it, but it should work if you build Kivy and its dependencies from source (excepting those packages like Cython and PIL that are already part of the Canopy distribution). For this purpose, Canopy's Python is just another Python, and Canopy's IDE is just another code editor. The generic Kivy instructions should suffice.